# Can Filezilla truly do FTPS?

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, filezilla, ftps

I tried logging into a FTPS server, but when trying to get a directory list, I get this error:

Response:   150 Opening data channel for directory list. 
Response:   425 Can't open data connection.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

Also, I don't see the option to use "Require explicit FTP over SSL". So I used  "Require explicit FTP over TLS" instead.

I am trying to log in to this server: 
Address ftp.secureftp-test.com
Login: test
Password: test

Any ideas? Thanks.

Here are the protocols Filezilla shows:

[No SSL http://www.twse2.com/noSSL.png](http://www.twse2.com/noSSL.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm running FileZilla 3.5.3 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 and it's working fine here.

It's also mentioned in the [FileZilla features](http://filezilla-project.org/client_features.php) that it should work. If you're running OS X/Linux I'd make sure OpenSSL is installed and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

check if Firewall is intercepting in between the connection.
once i had the same issue.